# Image morphing in node.js

Tags: node.js, morphing

Is it possible to do image morphing in Node.js using Javascript? I'm trying to find out whether it's possible to do something like this. Are there any node.js libraries that could be used to implement image morphing?

Comment: I know of a program called xmorph that has a command-line interface - that might be a good starting point.

Comment: Curious - what did you end up going with?

Comment: @bryanmac I decided to use xmorph - GraphicsMagick doesn't do image morphing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this one meets your morphing needs but there's a GraphicsMajick module here:

https://npmjs.org/package/gm

You can also search for modules @ npmjs.org

It supports manipulations like blur, charcoal, chop, colorize, despeckle, dither, dissolve, emboss, equalize, fuzz, gaussian, implode,magnify, matte, etc... etc...

Comment: What types of image morphing capabilities does this module have?

Comment: I mentioned some, the full list is about a third the way down the page under Methods, manipulations.

Comment: There's a JavaScript image morphing library available: https://github.com/jembezmamy/morpher-js