# How to rearrange images by pixel groups

Tags: image-processing, image-manipulation, morphing

I would like to create an image transition program. It should shift pixel areas from one image and transition them to another based on certain criteria, like colour and shape.

To do this, I need to be able to analyse the image, split it into groups, and shift these groups.

- The first problem already starts with determining the pixel groups. They should not be chosen at random or perfect polygons/shapes. Does anyone know of an algorithm that can differentiate different textures/surroundings/borders?
- Next, I need to do the slight adjustments to the areas in order to make them fit to the new image. Then the areas will be moved. That'll not be as hard as the first problem.

Performance doesn't matter that much; first I have to get the program working. It can take an hour to load the transition beforehand or whatever ;)

Could anyone give me some advice where to start or what technologies/APIs I could use? I'm fine with most programming languages, preferably C#, VB, JavaScript, PHP, Java, etc.  The platform doesn't matter either.

I know, this is complex, but I gave my best to try to explain it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first task, grouping according to color/texture/etc. is called [segmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation). There are many approaches and algorithms to do it, and none is absolutely better than all other, as many things in image processing, the best algorithm depends on your image and your specific functional/artistic goal.

The general idea is to define multiple distances between pixels, like one distance would be based only on the position of pixels, another on the difference in their color, a more advanced metric could take the neighborhood into account to do something related to shape, contour orientations or texture. Then you would combine these distances (for example in a weighted sum) to get a "clever" measure of how similar two pixels are. After that you compute more or less exhaustively all distances and group similar pixels according to some thresholds (like how big the final groups are).

If you don't want to research and implement all that, you'd be better off using an existing image processing library. I suggest looking at [OpenCV](http://opencv.org) and the "segmentation" keyword. You'll get implementations of k-means, watershed and meanshift algorithms which are probably of interest for achieving your effect.

OpenCV is C++ but it also have bindings in Java and Python I think, and probably other.

For your second task, you need a mix of moving and blending pixels, but that's simpler and you can do it "by hand", or look at [morphing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphing) algorithms.

A quick search revealed [this blog post](http://blog.polysfactory.com/2012/01/image-morphing.html) with a source code using OpenCV to morph two images. You also have some ready-made libraries in a few languages, have a look at [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737419/image-morphing-in-node-js) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612357/is-there-a-library-for-morphing-images-in-java-or-processing).

You could even directly call a command-line utility: [xmorph](http://xmorph.sourceforge.net/) but doesn't seem portable or imagemagick (see [this](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/shapemorph/) script) which is more modern but not doesn't implement a real morphing algorithm AFAIK.